# Is it possible to return a designated sub-set of an array of embedded documents from MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

For a query into the embedded documents I'd love to return the matching element, plus a pre-designated set of elements.For example, with

Say I have a collection like below:

```js
{_id: 1,
 data:[
    {who: 'Alice',  score: 20},
    {who: 'Brad',  score: 25},
    {who: 'Charlie',  score: 30},
    {who: 'Dave',  score: 40},
    {who: 'Elaine',  score: 50},
    {who: 'Frank',  score: 20}   

 ]},
 {_id: 2,
 data:[
    {who: 'Alice',  score: 30},
    {who: 'Brad',  score: 50},
    {who: 'Charlie',  score: 68},
    {who: 'Dave',  score: 20},
    {who: 'Elaine',  score: 50},
    {who: 'Frank',  score: 20}   

 ]},
   ...
```

If I need to always return Alice and Brad, and anyone with score equals 50, I tend to use

```js
find({data.score: 50}, {'data.who': {'$in': ['Alice', 'Brad', '$']}})
or 
aggregate([{'$match': {data.score: 50}}, 
           {'$project': {'data': 1}},
           {'$unwind': '$data'}, 
           {'$match': {'data.who': {'$in': ['Alice', 'Brad', '$']}}}])
```

unfortunately, neither works.

What would be the correct way to achieve it or is it even possible?

Comment: you want only   data.who = Alice , data.who = Brad and data.score = 50 is right?

Answer (score 1):

You can aggregate the result using the [**$redact**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/) stage. This removes the need of the [**$unwind**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage, which can prove to be quiet costly in case of large data sets.

- Use the `$redact` stage operator, to [**$$PRUNE**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune) sub documents
  that do not meet the criteria in the [**$cond**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond) expression.

Code:

```
 db.t.aggregate([
 {$redact:{$cond:[{$or:[{$eq:[{$ifNull:["$who","Alice"]},"Alice"]},
                        {$eq:[{$ifNull:["$who","Brad"]},"Brad"]},
                        {$eq:[{$ifNull:["$score",50]},50]}
                       ]},"$$DESCEND","$$PRUNE"]}}
 ])
```

Or you can make slight modification to the existing code as below:

- The `$match` condition should contain all the three conditions to
  retain a sub document.
- Then `$unwind`.
- Then apply the same `$match` condition again to select the un-winded
  documents.
- `$group` by `_id` to consolidate the selected data sub documents for
  each `_id`.

Code:

```
db.t.aggregate([
 {$match:{$or:[{"data.who":{$in:["Alice","Brad"]}},
               {"data.score":{$eq:50}}]}},
 {$unwind:"$data"},
 {$match:{$or:[{"data.who":{$in:["Alice","Brad"]}},
               {"data.score":{$eq:50}}]}},
 {$group:{"_id":"$_id","data":{$push:"$data"}}}
 ])
```

o/p:

```
{
        "_id" : 1,
        "data" : [
                {
                        "who" : "Alice",
                        "score" : 20
                },
                {
                        "who" : "Brad",
                        "score" : 25
                },
                {
                        "who" : "Elaine",
                        "score" : 50
                }
        ]
}
{
        "_id" : 2,
        "data" : [
                {
                        "who" : "Alice",
                        "score" : 30
                },
                {
                        "who" : "Brad",
                        "score" : 50
                },
                {
                        "who" : "Elaine",
                        "score" : 50
                }
        ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tested if `$redact` performs much better than `$unwind`? Both would need to examine each array element and so are "big O equivalent", but I'm wondering if you have experience with using both for the same job and have seen `$redact` give noticeable improvements? It's plausible that `$redact` does better than `$unwind` given that `$unwind` produces a bunch of extra documents.

Comment: I have not tested them for performance in large data sets. But at least theoretically redact should not produce copies of documents which would prove costly during the pipeline processing, which is the case of unwind. Will definitely try to measure the performance and post an update.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting $redact. Having played with it a little, it works as expected,  except that it may cause too large return document and throws like $unwind on my production db. can $regex be used with $redact? e.g. {$regex:["$v", /\d{2}/]}. I tried but it does not work. For the other suggestion, It works too, but I do like the fact that 2 $match stages of the same search critera  are involved.

Answer (score 0):

I think as per my understanding following query will match your criteria

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$unwind": "$data"
},
{
    "$match": {
    "$or": [
        {
            "data.score": 50
        },
        {
            "data.who": "Alice"
        },
        {
            "data.who": "Brad"
        }
    ]
    }
},
{
    "$project": {
    "_id": 0,
    "data": "$data"
    }
}).pretty()
```

Comment: Actually you don'y have to use two $or operators - one should do just fine "$or": [{"data.score": 50}, {"data.who": "Alice" }, { "data.who": "Brad" }]